# Jquery checkbox action in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'd like to have some jquery in my html on my custom wordpress page. Now this does work (from an example):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    alert("Action ABC")
});
});
</script>
```

Whereas this does not. There simply doesn't happen anything when the box is checked.

```
<p id="agre"> <input type="checkbox" name="agre">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
     $('#agre').click(function(){
            var agree_conf = confirm("Action A");
            if (agree_conf == true) {
                window.location = "http://www.google.com"
            }
         })
</script>
```

This has maybe to do with the proper jquery/wordpress call. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: The p-tag doesn't have closing tag, that breaks the dom, try adding the </p>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `});` to close your DOM ready handlder:

```
$(function () {
    $('#agre').click(function () {
        var agree_conf = confirm("Action A");
        if (agree_conf == true) {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com"
        }
    })
}); // <-- Here
```

Comment: That wasn't it. But your comment made me find my error: wordpress seems to put <p> tags wherever I insert a break in my script. Didn't know that. Adjusted it and changed the function to `$(document).ready(function(){`